# Запись данных в Firebase через другое активити

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database

Есть 2 активити. В одном активити первый пользователь вводит значения и передет их в главное активити через onActivityResult и одновременно сохраняет в Firebase. Пользователь Находящийся в главном активити не видит данные, пока первый пользователь не выйдет из второго активити в главное. Как сделать запись данных автоматически, без закрытия первого активити?

Comment: Вопрос не очень ясен. Точнее, не ясно что у вас происходит и почему разные юзеры на разных активити. Может они на разных девайсах? Может вам надо писать данные не в момент выхода, а в другой момент, по клику например? Или вы ожидаете, что одновременно будут несколько активити жить? Если последнее - то это не получится - андроид так не работает.

Comment: Скорее всего я понял в чем ошибка. Метод onAtivityResult срабатывает только  после выхода из второго активити . Поэтому у меня и данные скачиваются с базы данных только так. Как можно сделать по-другому?

Comment: Все ещё не ясно что и в каком порядке у вас делается. Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос

Comment: Есть приложение для 8ми человек. У каждого пользователя есть свое активити, в котором они в edittext вводят данные и с помощью кнопки "сохранить" данные сохраняются в firebase. Все данные с активити передаются в главное активити. Но проблема в том, что данные в главное активити попадают только тогда, когда пользователь, введя данные, выйдет из своего активити. Хотя значения в главном активити я привязал в firebase.

Comment: Пока активити какое-то на экране все остальные активити следует считать мёртвыми. Т.е. вы не можете манипулировать ими из других активити. Т.е. ваша проблема - это стандартное и ожидаемое поведение. Напишите чего вы хотите здесь поменять и зачем - возможно вы не под тем углом на проблему смотрите? Может вам просто надо данные не в активити хранить/получать/обновлять, но в некоем глобальном синглтоне? В общем всё ещё не совсем ясно почему обновление данных при возврате из активити - проблема.

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы по нажатию кнопки "сохранить значение" данные сразу обновлялись и в главном активити, не выходя из своего активити. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Сделать буквально так - невозможно, т.к. главная активити мертва пока вы в другой находитесь. Но вы можете использовать глобальный синглтон, в коем данные будете хранить и в главной активити в onResume из него данные отображать.